# Issue stacking two swf emebeds over each other, adsense for games

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, embed, flash, adsense

I'm having a issue with this.  I am trying to get the adsense for games swf to show before the game.

The problem is that it just shows a clear box.  And I get this adsense error in the console.

```
"Error: Ad adLoadError error: Parameter linearAdSlotWidth must be greater than 0. errorCode: 1103:ArgumentError: Parameter linearAdSlotWidth must be greater than 0.
```

Here is my embed code.

```
<div class="text-center embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 text-center " >


    <div id="a">
        <object
            classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
            codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0"
            width="500" height="500"
            id="preloader"
            align="middle">
            <!--allowScriptAccess must always be set to always-->
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
            <param name="movie" value="ima3_preloader_1.5.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />

            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="adTagUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpagead%2Fads%3Fad_type%3Dvideo_image_text_flash%26client%3Dca-games-pub-123123123123%26videoad_start_delay%3D0%26description_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%26max_ad_duration%3D40000">
            <param name="WMode" value="Transparent" />
            <embed src="/static/ima3_preloader_1.5.swf"
                    quality="high" bgcolor="#000000"
                    width="500" height="500"
                    name="preloader"
                    align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always"
                    allowFullScreen="false"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    flashVars="adTagUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpagead%2Fads%3Fad_type%3Dvideo_image_text_flash%26client%3Dca-games-pub-123123123123%26videoad_start_delay%3D0%26description_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%26max_ad_duration%3D40000"
                    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />

        </object>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/static{{ game.game_swf }}" width="200" height="200">
            <param name="movie" value="/static{{ game.game_swf }}" />
            <param name="WMode" value="Transparent" />
        </object>
    </div>



</div>
```

Here is the css

```
#a {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:10;
}
#b {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:20;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The css required width.

```
#a {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:10;
   width:100%;
}
#b {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:20;
   width:100%;
}
```